# Laravel. How to exclude rows where the value is equal to 0?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am running a query and save the results in a file. The SELECT looks like this:

```
$providers = groups::select('groups.id', DB::raw('count(DISTINCT groups_selection_filter.objectFK) as providers_total'))
```

But there are clients where the COUNT of `providers_total` is equal to zero. For instance:

```
1759 => array:5 [
    "id" => 1759
    "name" => "Test Client"
    "provider_count" => 0 
    "sport_count" => 1
    "sport_name" => "Soccer"
  ]
```

I need to remove such clients from the returned results. Tried with whereNot and HAVING

```
->havingRaw(DB::raw('count(DISTINCT groups_selection_filter.objectFK)', '!==', 0))
```

But so far without success...any ideas?

Comment: @DreamBold In select and in having results in an error

Comment: Its not working like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get the results I wanted like this: After the query using

```
$only_ids = array_keys($compliance);
```

And later in my 2nd and 3rd query using the where in like that:

```
->whereIn('groups.id', $only_ids)
```